# Compare json file and dropdown values displayed in an inorderly way

Tags: javascript, json, cypress

I have my JSON file with the following text[there are around 100 values I have just put 4 here]

```json
{
  label: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
}
```

I have my dropdown in my website which has these values but in a different order.

How can I compare that the text from the JSON and dropdown values are equal?

Also, I have a text "ALL" which is displayed in the dropdown by default and is not included in the JSON file. It's like this: enter image description here

In the dropdown, the rest of the values are in the JSON file.

I have done the below but it is not working.

```
cy.fixture('label.json')
    .then(function (category) {
           this.cat = category
      })
})
cy.get('#labels').each(($ele, i) => {
      expect($ele).to.have.text(this.category.label[i])
      })
})
```

Any help will be highly appreciated Thank you

Answer (score 3):

One way is to map the option elements to an array of label texts

**HTML**

```html
<select name="labels" id="labels">
  <option value="" selected="">ALL</option>
  <option value="a">a</option> 
  <option value="c">c</option> 
  <option value="b">b</option> 
  <option value="d">d</option>
</select>
```

**Test**

```js
cy.get('option')
  .then($options => Cypress.$.map($options, (option => option.innerText)))
  .then(optionLabels => {  

    // optionLabels is ['ALL', 'a', 'c', 'b', 'd']

    cy.fixture('my-labels.json'),then(fixture => {

      const expected = fixture.label.concat(['ALL'])  // add the ALL
      // expected is ['a', 'c', 'b', 'd', 'ALL']

      expect(optionLabels).to.have.members(expected)  // .to.have.members checks with any order
    })
  })
```

**Result**

[image]

**When missing an option**

[image]

---

#### Truncated option text

When your option text is truncated but you want to match to text in the fixture,

```
"clarif..." -> "clarification"
```

you can transform the fixture data before comparing.

Also, since there are 124 entries, it is better to just log any failures rather than the whole list.

```html
<select>
  <option>ALL</option>
  <option>clarif...</option>
  <option>a</option>
  <option>d</option>
  <option>b</option>
</select>
```

```js
cy.get('option')
  .then($options => Cypress.$.map($options, (option => option.innerText)))
  .then(console.log)
  .then(optionLabels => {

    cy.fixture('my-labels.json').then(fixture => {

      const truncate = (text) => text.length > 6 ? text.slice(0,6) + '...' : text;

      const expected = fixture.label.concat(['ALL'])      // add ALL
        .map(truncate)                 // convert fixture to short strings 

      const notInDropdown = expected.filter(exp => !optionLabels.includes(exp))
      const extraInDropdown = optionLabels.filter(label => !expected.includes(label))

      if (notInDropdown.length) {
        throw `Not in dropdown: ${notInDropdown.join(' ')}`
      }
      if (extraInDropdown.length) {
        throw `Extra in dropdown: ${extraInDropdown.join(' ')}`
      }
      cy.log('Dropdown passes')
    })
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```js
cy.fixture("labels.json").then((labels) => {
  cy.get("select#labels option").each(($ele, i) => {
    if ($ele.text().trim() == "ALL") {
      expect(labels.label).to.not.include($ele.text().trim())
    } else {
      expect(labels.label).to.include($ele.text().trim())
    }
  })
})
```

Test runner:

[image: test runner screenshot]

Comment: Thank you.I am getting assertion error. It is saying expected a to include b,c,d,a[the text in my dropdown]
Also how do i make the loop ignore the "ALL" displayed in the dropdown since itis displayed by default and will not appear in the json file.

Comment: Is it because of 'ALL' ? I have updated my answer. Also I have assumed that the fixture file is named `labels.json` and is under `cypress/fixtures`.

Comment: Can you log `cy.log($ele.text())` and `cy.log(labels.label[0])` inside each and tell me what you see ?

Comment: Yes it is under cypress/fixtures. I ave added the code but getting error in the line if ($ele.text().trim() == "ALL") {
should it be === insteadof  ==?

Comment: I am getting same assertion error. expected a to include ALL, b, c, a ,d when adding cy.log($ele.text()) and cy.log(labels.label[0]) inside each

Comment: Please remove everything else except the two log statement and tell me what you get.

Comment: For the first one i got all the options from the dropdown
For the second one i got the first option from my json file

Comment: If you are using an each loop you should get just one option from the webpage not all the options. Please check the selector OR add the html here.`labels.label[0]` can be changed to `labels.label`

Comment: <select name="labels" id="labels">
<option value="" selected="">ALL</option>
<option value="a">a</option>
<option value="c">c</option>
<option value="b">b</option>
<option value="d">d</option> 

I have added the code snippet. Not sure how to put it in code format here

Comment: Changed the locator from `#labels` to `select#labels option`. Can you try now. This should work. I have updated my answer.

Comment: I am getting:


expected [ Array(124) ] to not include ALL - This is ok
expected [ Array(124) ] to include 'c'  -This is failing

Also the line if ($ele.text().trim() == "ALL") {   - is highlighted in red

Comment: Please check your JSON file, it doesn't contain c. I have run this locally and it works perfectly. You can check the added test runner screenshot.

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible to get the very close text as my dropdown has the text like this:
clarifi....
but my json will have the full text like clarification... the code is not finding c because c is c...
whereas in my json file it is in full text

Comment: Can you post the html of the of the element text `clarifi....`

Comment: Its like this:
<option value="a">clarifi...</option>